# Change image alpha from listview position and save

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, kotlin, baseadapter

I'm making a music listview. I have a base adapter and music class music class have 3 property; name:String
point:String
image:Int
how can i change image alpha which item selected?

```
        listMusics.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
        val preference = getSharedPreferences("PREFS",0)
        val editor = preference.edit()
        best1 = preference.getInt("best1", 0)
        if(best1>=position*100) {
            music = position
            view.imgMusic.alpha=1F
            editor.putInt("music", music)
            editor.apply()
        }

    }
```

i'm changing image alpha with   `view.imgMusic.alpha=1F` it's change alpha to image but i can't save item alpha. i want to change alpha to 1F which item selected and save also change the other items to 0.5F how can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use ImageView to show image than you can use this property:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:alpha="0.4" // <-----------------  this
    android:background="@drawable/imagename"
/>
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: I want to change which item selected. Your method change every item

Answer (score 0):

in adapter onBindViewHolder you can use this code

```
 holder.container.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        lastSelectedSong = position;

        //reset the color of all items and change color of new selected item
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    });

    //change icon and color of last Selected Song
    if (position == lastSelectedSong) {
        holder.container.setBackgroundColor(your_color);

           } else { //default color and icon of items
        holder.imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
```